Blazored LocalStorage SetItemAsStringAsync not working in a button-triggered page function
I have a Blazor (.net 8) page code function that uses Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService to set a page cookie.  If I execute the SetItemAsStringAsync in a page event, say OnAfterRenderAsync, it works.  However, what I want is a "login" button that once triggered sets the cookie - so it calls a function that performs SetItemAsStringAsync - and when I set a breakpoint on that line and step over it, the next line is never executed, and the page is refreshed.
In other words, I want to set the user email address in a local storage cookie when he clicks the "Login" button, not on page load.  If I use the set item function in page load, it works - but in a button, it does not.
Here is my code:
private async Task UserLogin()
{
   var loginresult = Utils.AuthenticateUser(authUser.Email, authUser.Password);
   var user = await Utils.DataInterface.GetUser(authUser.Email);
   if (loginresult)
   {
      await localStorage.SetItemAsStringAsync("website.login", user.Email);
   }
}

The above fails.  The user variable is an object returned from an EntityFramework database call.

I have no idea why, but if I replace the returned EntityFramework object user.Email with the local authUser.Email, it works.
I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but it is bound to a Postgres database.  For some reason, I cannot store any EF retrieved property in local storage.  If anyone knows why, please respond.

Again, I have ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA why that worked, but today it does not.  I can set the value to a string literal in the code, but not to any variable value anymore.  If I set a breakpoint on the line, when I step over it, the next line never continues - it simply refreshes the browser page to clear the form, and aborts the code execution.  Does anyone have an idea why this is or how to fix?  I can't imagine I'm the only one experiencing this.
